# Avoid multiple page redirects http://example.com > https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site is slowing down due to multiple page redirects, as reported by GTMetrix and Google Pagespeed Insights if a user types domain.com:

```
URL:                       TIME SPENT:
http://example.com/        285ms
https://example.com/       452ms
https://www.example.com    0ms
```

I'm trying to get to just one (conditional?) redirect that will always end up in the https and www subdomain.

This is the current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

It works, but is there anyone obsessed with speed that can help to make it faster into just one rewrite condition?

I searched endlessly at Stack overflow (and elsewhere) but no alternatives are combining everything in one statement with conditions and make it faster than the present solution.

I'd really appreciate your insights!

Comment: The rule is already faster as it redirects your `http` and `non-www` URLs to `https://www` in a single redirect.

Comment: As Amit already mentioned it looks ok from your rules side. How about giving it a shot to check from network site? may be network packets or traces etc while making requests to see if its all right from that side too. Honestly I am not an expert but if all is well from rules side, then I would have given it a shot to at least tick mark this check in troubleshooting list.

Answer (score 3):

Change the R flag to 301:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

because by default, it is a 302 (Temporary) redirect, and you avoid very many redirects.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html